# For loop only working on second loop with React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a project that I am going to add tags, similar to this site.  I want to first check if the tag has already been selected by the user.  I have a for loop to see if the tag added equals the tags that are already there.

If I make a tag named Jack, it will work just fine.  If I create another tag named Jack, now I have two Jacks(not good).  On the third attempt, it doesn't add another Jack (good.)

Here is my relevant code.  I have added the console as well.  My useState setTagAlreadyThere on is being ignored until the third attempt, when it should go to true on the second attempt.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
const [tagsFound, setTagsFound] = useState([])
const [tagsAdded, setTagsAdded] = useState([])    
const [tagAlreadyThere, setTagAlreadyThere] = useState(false)

const gatherTags = (tags) => {
    setTagAlreadyThere(false)
    console.log(tagAlreadyThere)

    if (tagsAdded.length === 0) {
        setTagsAdded([...tagsAdded, tags]);
    } else {
        console.log(tagsAdded)

        for (let i = 0; i < tagsAdded.length; i++) {
            console.log(tagsAdded[i])

            if (tags === tagsAdded[i]) {
                console.log(tagsAdded[i])
                console.log(tags)
                setTagAlreadyThere(true)
                console.log(tagAlreadyThere)
            }
        }
        console.log(tagAlreadyThere)
        if (tagAlreadyThere === false) {
            setTagsAdded([...tagsAdded, tags]);
            console.log(tagsAdded)
        } else {
            return
        }
    }

    setPostTag('')
}
```

Console.

```
TagAdder.tsx:9 jack
postarticle.tsx:64 false
postarticle.tsx:69 ["jack"]
postarticle.tsx:72 jack
postarticle.tsx:75 jack
postarticle.tsx:76 jack
postarticle.tsx:78 false
postarticle.tsx:81 false
postarticle.tsx:84 ["jack"]
post.tsx:6 {}
postarticle.tsx:92 (2) ["jack", "jack"]
post.tsx:6 {}
postarticle.tsx:
```

92

Comment: Where is your hooks?

Comment: just useState.  I'll post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no offense but you code has so many unnecessary stuff.

So why it is happening.  Because you `tagAlreadyThere` is not updated yet. And you are checking it is value.

```js
const gatherTags = (tags) => {
    if (!tagsAdded.inlcudes(tags)) {
      setTagsAdded([...tagsAdded, tags]);
      setPostTag('')
    }
}
```

No need for  `const [tagAlreadyThere, setTagAlreadyThere] = useState(false)`

Comment: Offense?  No sir, I totally agree with you.  I'm still learning, about a year in, and am trying super hard to get my code tighter.  I appreciate your AWESOME answer!

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an idea on why this code causes a lot of issues, no offense.

First is you call a hook inside a loop synchronously, because **React.useState** hook is asynchronous just like **this.setState** in class-based and it batches updates to gain performance.

I have an example here on Code Sandbox: [Calling Hooks Sync and Async](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-bouman-6ov3n)

Second is if your new state is computed from the previous state, use the callback style because you can access the updated previous state, example:

```
setTagsAdded(prevTagsAdded => [...prevTagsAdded, tags])
```

You can check the documentation here: [Functional Updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Hope this helps!